# Is the product of Jacobson rings a Jacobson ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory

Is the product 
$$
\prod_{i\in I}R_i
$$ 
of a family $(R_i)_{i\in I}$ of [Jacobson rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_ring) a Jacobson ring?

(Here "ring" means "commutative ring with one".)

Comment: Certainly a finite product of Jacobson rings with identity is Jacobson... Also an infinite product of fields is Jacobson.  
But I guess most infinite products are not.  How about $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @BadamBaplan Can you sketch the argument for fields ? (I know how to describe the maximal ideals of these, but not the prime ideals)

Comment: @Max - Products of von Neumann regular rings are von Neumann regular. Von Neumann regular rings are Jacobson. Fields are von Neumann regular. Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring

Comment: (And in particular, von Neumann regular rings are 0-dimensional, so the prime ideals *are* maximal)

Comment: Thank you Pierre-Yves ! As for $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ my worry is that neither its prime ideals nor its maximal ideals are easy to describe (there's a whole bunch of prime ideals of the form $\{x \mid \{i, x_i \in p_i\} \in \mathcal{U}\}$ for a given ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $\mathbb{N}$ and a given family of prime ideals $p_i \in Spec(\mathbb{Z})$ (and this is maximal whenever all $p_i$'s are nonzero); but I'm not sure these are the only ones. (@BadamBaplan yes indeed, that's the proof I thought of when reading Pierre-Yves' comment)

Comment: On the plus (maybe?) the minimal primes of $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ are in bijection with the ultrafilters.  

But yes on second thought maybe $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ isn't the best place to look.  Perhaps better to look at an infinite product of zero-dimensional (non-reduced) rings

Comment: Indeed, but those are probably actually intersections of maximal ideals (I don't know, but I'd guess the minimal prime ideal associated to $\mathcal{U}$ is the intersection of all the maximal ideals associated to $\mathcal{U}$ - the intersection would run over all families $(p_i)$ -)

Comment: It is, and here's a proof: let $x$ be such that $I=\{i, x_i =0\}\notin \mathcal{U}$. For $i\notin I$, let $p_i$ be a prime that doesn't divide $x_i$, and for $i\in I, p_i=2$. Then $x$ isn't in the maximal ideal associated to the $(p_i)$ and $\mathcal{U}$. So unless there are other types of prime ideals, this wouldn't work

Comment: hmm yes, good point!  I just found this paper which seems very relevant, if somebody was interested in settling the question for $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$.  But again, I'm not sure if this is barking up the wrong tree. http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm138/fm138114.pdf

Comment: Crossposted: https://mathoverflow.net/q/301014/461

Comment: The question has been answered by Luc Guyot on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/a/301073/461